# Pyest coverage failing but entire test passes

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, test-coverage

```
def func1(id, items):

    getRandomArray = func2(id)

    newItems = items
    if getRandomArray != None:
        newItems = [getRandomArray[index] for index in getRandomArray]
    return newItems

def test_func1self):
    with mock.patch(
        "path_to_func2.func2",
        return_value = [1,2,0,3,4,5],
    ):
        testfunc1 = func1(123, [0,1,2,3,4,5])
    expected = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5]
    assert testfunc1 == expected
```

For some reason my test above passes sucessfully but pytest tells me there is coverage missing on lines

```
if getRandomArray != None:
    newItems = [getRandomArray[index] for index in getRandomArray]
return newItems
```

This does not make sense to me since the test result was correct so I assume I am missing something about the pytest behaviour ?

The path I set is to the place func2 is called not where it is defined. If I change the mock patch to something invalid the test fails as expected so I do believe it is working

Comment: The message is telling you that because your test forces `func2()` to return a fixed value, the line `if getRandomArray != None` will _always_ be true, and so your test does not cover all possible cases.

Comment: @JohnGordon moments like this make me embarrassed to be a developer, thank you for spotting that !